# Is there a solution in protractor to scroll folowing filled elements?

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm a facing a problem where I want to fill my form, but it's only possible when inputs are visible (correct scroll position). I can't display all inputs at once. Is there any solution to make scroll follow current inputs?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.executeScript('let element = document.getElementById("<element>"); element.scrollIntoView();).then(function() { element(by.<<here your button locator>>).click(); })
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but still with this solution I must calculate all fields' y-coordinate. Isn't there any built-in mechanism to deal with this issue?

Comment: I have Updated the  answer

Comment: Now you don't have to deal with coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `.getLocation()` ?

> **Protractor API**: "Schedules a command to compute the location of this element in page space. 
>   A promise that will be resolved to the element's location as a `{x:number, y:number}` object."

You could try the following:

```
const input = element(by.id('yourId'));

GetLocationAndScroll = async (element) => {
    let {x, y} = await element.getLocation();
    return await browser.executeScript(`window.scrollTo(${x},${y});`);
};

GetLocationAndScroll(input);
```

Haven't really tested it so I dont know if it will work.
Let me know anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something I am missing in this question I think a simple .scrollIntoView is the best option for you. You could implement in the following two ways

**Option 1:** Create function

```
async function sendKeysWithScroll(requiredEle, value){
    await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", requiredEle.getWebElement());
    await requiredEle.sendKeys(value);    
}

const nameField = element(by.css('#name'));
await sendKeysWithScroll(nameField, "DublnDev");
```

---

**Option 2:** Alter ElementFinder prototype

**conf.js**

```
onPrepare: function () {

    //Add new prototype which scrolls into view before entering text
    require("protractor").ElementFinder.prototype.sendKeysWithScroll = async function (value) {
        await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", this.getWebElement());
        await this.sendKeys(value);
    }
}
```

**spec.js**

```
const nameField = element(by.css('#name'));
await nameField.sendKeysWithScroll("DublinDev");
```